# how to read .msg file in php

Tags: php, msg

I want to read Outlook `.msg` email with PHP language and I don't know how to read it with simple file read function.

I have enabled **Mailparse extension** in my Linux system and by using it I can read the `.eml` files correctly but not `.msg`.

Could you point me to correct code or library I need to use?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/hfig/MAPI will do it.

```
        require 'autoload.php';


        $newfn= "outlook.msg";
        // message parsing and file IO are kept separate
        $messageFactory = new Hfig\MAPI\MapiMessageFactory();
        $documentFactory = new Hfig\MAPI\OLE\Pear\DocumentFactory();

        $ole = $documentFactory->createFromFile($newfn);
        $message = $messageFactory->parseMessage($ole);

        // raw properties are available from the "properties" member
        echo $message->properties['subject'], "\n";

        // some properties have helper methods
        echo $message->getSender(), "\n";
        echo $message->getBody(), "\n";

        // recipients and attachments are composed objects
        foreach ($message->getRecipients() as $recipient) {
            // eg "To: John Smith <john.smith@example.com>
            echo sprintf('%s: %s', $recipient->getType(), (string)$recipient), "\n";
        }
        exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse using `Aspose_Email_Java_for_PHP` Download [here](https://github.com/aspose-email/Aspose.Email-for-Java/tree/master/Plugins/Aspose_Email_Java_for_PHP)

## Some example

```
$mapiMessage=new MapiMessage();
$outlook_message_file = $mapiMessage->fromFile($dataDir . "Message.msg");
```

## Display sender's name

```
print "Sender Name : " . $outlook_message_file->getSenderName();
```

## Display Subject

```
print "Subject : " . $outlook_message_file->getSubject();
```

## Display Body

```
print "Body : " . $outlook_message_file->getBody();
```

Reference : 
https://asposeemailjavaphp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/aspose/email/ProgrammingOutlook/WorkingWithOutlookMessageFiles/ParseOutlookMessageFile.php

Comment: Thanks for you reply
any other way without using java with php

Comment: for Aspose_Email_Java_for_PHP i need to installed java on server that i do not want

Comment: How to get the attachments from a msg file ? Is it possible using the Aspose library?